# How to send your game info to your opponent before calling finishGame() using Google's Turn Based Multiplayer API

Tags: java, android, google-api, persistence, multiplayer

I am creating an app that implements Google's turn based multiplayer api. The way I have everything setup the starting player has his turn skipped when the match starts so that their byte array of info. can be sent to the opponent to be used to populate the view. Once the opponent is finished, they send their byte array to the player that started the match so they can then populate their view also.

Once both of these turns are taken, since the starting player is the last one to take a turn, I call finishMatch(). Now, the starting player is finished and can no longer interact with the match. The opponent now needs to interact with the match one more time: this is to get the score difference between the two players since the opponent was the first to actually act upon a view.

The issue I am having is, how do I get the byte array back to the opponent again? When I call persist() from the starting player's turn and then call unpersist inside the opponents turn, the opponent ends up with their own score. (The data I am worried about is a score that is passed between the two players. The opponent goes first and sends their score to the starting player. The starting player goes and knows if they won or not, then finishes the game, but the opponent now needs to know who won.)

The persist() call is what takes all of the particular player's info and throws it into a byte array to be sent to the opponent. The unpersist() call is what goes through the byte array and produces a string that I parse to populate my views.

I am clearly not thinking about this right. I could really use a pointer from someone that knows the google turn based multiplayer api well. Please let me know if you have any ideas or would like code to clarify anything.